# My relational database structure is getting too large and I don't know how to shrink it

Tags: database, data-structures, relational-database

My new employer runs a standard ecommerce website with about 14k products.  They create "microsites" that a person can log into and see custom pricing and limited products (hide some/show some products) and custom categories.

The current system is just has a huge relational database. So there is a products table, a sites table and then sites_products has the following columns

```
site_id
product_id
product_price
```

If the microsite is suppose to show a product it simply stores it in this table. This table is currently @ 2 million rows and growing.  The custom categories is a similar relational table setup but the numbers are much lower so I am not as worried about that.

I would appreciate any help/ideas you could provide to decrease this table size. I am confident that in the next couple years it will be at 20 million at this rate.

-Justin

Comment: 2 million rows is hardly considered large nowadays. And 20 million is more like medium sized. Why do you think that is a problem? Btw: which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Yeah, this looks like it is "by design."  Allowing for eight bytes for each id, and sixteen bytes for each price, you're still only going to be at about 640 megabytes for the linking table (not counting indexes, of course), and it's probably going to be serving hundreds of microsites.

Comment: This is on mysql...this solution doesn't seem to be scalable...we are only at around 150 microsites now....in 10 years it could be 1500 easily.

Comment: Are you already having performance problems?  MySQL can handle tables that are two *terabytes* in size, unless you're still running it on FAT32. To reiterate, *your design seems sound.*  You can't economize further without removing functionality.

Comment: Thanks for your time, I appreciate it.  I think I have a way to calculate the price dynamically via information from the site table.  What about a way to simply hide/show products on a per "microsite" basis.

Comment: I'm still not convinced you have a problem.  Is a pointy-haired boss telling you to fix it?

Comment: Lol...well I am rebuilding how the cart/product system works anyway so now is the best to time to address the situation.  The situation, in my mind, is that the current setup won't work properly with a relatively small number of microsites (1500 x 15000(products) == 22.5m records on a table that needs to get queried pretty often).  That said, if there is nothing I can do fair enough...the only thing I can think of doing is isolate the microsite products to their own table that only gets used if the customer logs into a microsite.